# How to get IE9 to set content type when uploading directly to S3

Tags: internet-explorer, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

When using version 4.0.3 uploading directly to AWS S3, uploads sent through IE9 will have the content type set to binary/octet-stream rather than the actual content type of the file uploaded.

This does not occur in Firefox/Chrome (haven't tested safari).

What is the trick to getting the content type set on IE9 (or below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, AWS will set a Content-Type of "application/octet-stream" on the object if one is not specified as a request parameter.  We send a Content-Type parameter in modern browsers based on the `type` property available on the associated `Blob` object that we are uploading.  IE9 and older don't have support for the File API, so we would have to maintain a table of extensions to MIME types internally in order to send the same information along with the request for IE9 and older.  It's not clear that this would be worth the effort.

Quite frankly this is somewhat of a shortcoming of S3, as it should simply use the Content-Type parameter inside of the file's multipart boundary (if the request is MPE).  I'm not sure why S3 doesn't just parse this value.

Why is this information important to you?  This value is not guaranteed to be correct anyway, as it is based on the file extension, which may or may not accurately describe the file container.  If you want to properly identify a file's type, you should do so via magic byte parsing.

Comment: It's only important for files that are later made public and served direct from S3.  Our keys don't include extensions (so we don't have to maintain a mapping to them in our application - they are just an ID.  I can fix up the content type later in the process, but I was curious what the technical reason was.  Thanks for responding so promptly.